# How to initialize and run Docker on windows?

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

I have Docker installed on Windows 7 platform. However when I try to run boot2docker start, the console gives me:

> Failed to get machine 'boot2docker-vm': machine does not exist.

Ok, so I try to initialize the machine: boot2docker init. What now happens is even though I have the ISO image on the same path as docker, it tries to download a new image (and then fails to do so).

I uninstalled both OracleVM and GIT before installing them with boot2docker bundle as advised on Docker forums, but now I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: which boot2docker version？ did u remove ～/.boot2docker ？did you work in intranet？did u see boot2docker-vm crreated in virtualbox ？any picture or other exact log can be shared？

Comment: version: 1.12. I did not remove .boot2docker. intranet: yes! no, I don't see boot2docker-vm in virtualbox. Cannot share exact log, but it had to do with not being able to dowload the ISO (I guess due to me being in intranet). However I have the ISO already so I can't see why it tries to download at all.

Comment: you can debug the start.sh by yourself, it may conflict with your setting, you need set proxy in start.sh to download ISO, but ISO is inside the apckage. You'd better to provide some logs (remove sensitive info)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a Windows 7 64 bit system when I installed the entire boot2docker package. It seems that running the solely 64-bit based boot2docker image from a 32-bit OS image (e.g. created by Virtualbox) does not work.

The solution for me was

1. to activate Intel Virtualisation Technolologies in my BIOS
   (Lenovo X61 for me). Note that the settings can be found either
   under CPU or Security.
2. choose a 64 bit OS version in VirtualBox and boot in with the
   image obtained by boot2docker.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're trying to do this now

1. For Windows 10 64-bit: Pro, Enterprise, or Education (Build 15063 or later), follow the instructions to install Docker Desktop here https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/.
2. If you have Windows systems that do not meet the requirements of Docker Desktop for Windows(in my case Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language), you can install Docker Toolbox by following the instructions here https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/.

Answer (score -1):

boot2docker does not support sharing directories on Windows IIRC. The way I run Docker on windows is:

- install VirtualBox
- install Vagrant
- create a directory (let's say `c:\vm\docker`)
- download this [Vagrantfile](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thomasleveil/55755b2556984c06417c/raw/Vagrantfile) and save it under `c:\vm\docker\Vagrantfile`
- open a DOS command prompt
- go to the directory `cd c:\vm\docker`
- start the VM `vagrant up` and wait for it to install, start up and get provisionned
- connect to the VM `vagrant ssh`
- play with docker `docker images`, etc

Also you might want a real console instead of using the DOS command prompt:

- install [Git Bash for Windows](http://git-scm.com/download/win)
- install [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)
- setup Console to use Git Bash (see [this](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/05/integrating-the-git-bash-into-console/) guide)
- use Console to run the `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh` commands

Comment: You don't answer the question. Use another tool isn't an answer.

Comment: while my answer does not instruct how to fix issues with boot2docker and Windows, it does answer `How to initialize and run Docker on windows?` which is the actual question

Comment: The question is formulated for boot2docker and even tagged for it.

Comment: Thomas, thank you for your answer! However I did want to use boot2docker as suggested by Docker documentation (?). I know that I could run a virtual Linux distribution for example and use Docker there.